# How do I prevent this link leaking for my email?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I'm sending an email through Swift Mailer for an activation email. The user must click a button to activate their account, but the link boundaries are extending beyond the button. How do I fix this problem without inserting the `a tags` inside the main element? Then, the text would be clickable, but not the parent div.

```html
<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>
            <div style='border: 1px solid #CCC;width:538px;font-family:Helvetica; padding: 30px'>
              <span style='font-size: 30px;text-align: center;color: #606060;font-weight: bold;'> Just one more step... </span>
                <br> <br> <br>
               
<a href='#' style='text-decoration: none'> <div style='color: white; padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px; background: #69B8D6; border: 1px solid #69B8D6;text-align: center;width: 156px;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;border-radius:3px;'> Activate Account </div> </a> </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```